# How to create 2 or more different registration pages in Drupal 7

Tags: blocks, users

I'm trying to create (on this, my first project) 2 user registration pages, one for free, the other one could be a 'paid' subscription sign up via UberCart. I'm using AutoAssignRole, Profile2, Views, roles.
I'm sure it is really very easy, but I seem to be going around in circles and not getting anywhere. Maybe I can't see the 'logic' for the 'trees'.
The Drupal forums lack any specific answers.

I'm running a Dev machine on an Ubuntu localhost (without WAMP) prior to any.
It's all very frustrating and I'm trying to learn ASAP as to get back in to work. Does any one have a simple answer, or any suggestion for a tutorial on the above?
I'm a newbie to Drupal 7 and web programming, but I have 25 years of experience in IT, previously on Microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Could [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) suffice for what you need to accomplish with the second registration form?

I actually did something similar recently, using a webform as a second registration form. I used the original registration form for the basic registration and on the second form I used [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) to perform actions when the webform was submitted. Of course, this could also be done with a simple fielded node and Rules, but I liked the extra features that webform offered in doing this. If this project can be accomplished with nodes/Rules or Webform/Webform Rules then that can certainly offer you a lot of flexibility in updating the forms in the future as well.

Comment: For now I solved the above issue with the https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan module.